# SQLite issue - DB is locked workaround

Tags: linux, sqlite

I have 2 processes that connect to the same DB.
The first one is used to read from the DB and the second is used to write to the DB.
The first process sends write procedures for executing to the second process via message-queue on linux.

Every SQL-statement is taken in the prepare, step, finalize routine; Where the prepare and step are made in loop of 10000 times till it succedd (did this to overcome DB locked issues).

To add a table i do the next procedure:

1. the first process sends request via msg-q to the second process to add a table and insert garbage in it's rows in a journal_mode=OFF mode.
2. then the first process checks for the existing table so it could continue in its algorithm. (It checks it in a loop with usleep command between iterations.)

The problem is that the second process is stuck in the step execute of 'PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF;' because it says the DB is locked (Here too, i use a loop of 10000 iterations with usleep to check 10000 time for the DB to be free, as i mentioned before).

When i add to the first process in the 'check for existing table' loop, the operation of closing the connection, the second process is ok. But now when i add tables and values sometime i get 'callback requested query abort' in the Step Statement.

Any help of whats happening here ?

Comment: Maybe your process wants to switch off journal_mode while the other process is writing to the DB. Try to do a ROLLBACK before turning off the journal_mode.

Comment: The first process isn't writing to the DB, only has a connection for reading the DB. The second process is the one that switch off the journal_mode and later on writing to that DB.

Comment: Do you have any result sets/cursors open on the reader side while waiting for the write to happen?

Comment: coude be that the reading process is reading from the DB and has an sqlite3_stmt open, but why should it bother the writing process? Anyway, i checked for performance of writing the DB in both journal_mode=WAL and journal_mode=OFF and there isn't much difference. Eventually, the WAL is faster, so i use it instead of switching off the journal_mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use WAL mode. It allows one writer and any number of readers without any problems. You don't need to check for the locked state and do retrys etc.

WAL limitation: The DB has to be on the local drive.

Performance: Large transactions (1000s of inserts or similar) are slower than classic rollback journal, but apart of that the speed is very similar, sometimes even better. Perceived performance (UI waiting for DB write to finish) improves dramatically.

WAL is a new technology, but already used in Firefox, Adroid/iOS phones etc. I did tests with 2 threads running at full speed - one writing and the other one reading - and did not encounter a single problem.

You may be able to simplify your app when adopting the WAL mode.

Comment: I find that WAL is fast as OFF. I have to be fast cause in the init procedure i have to build all the tables, and in run-time update the values in them. Are there any suggestions to speed up the init procedure? The init procedure isn't have to be stable as the run-time procedure so the DB can be risk to corrupt.

Comment: What about running (during Init) without any journal at all? You can additionally use PRAGMA synchronous=0 and locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE. Then you re-open the DB with standard settings and WAL.

Comment: A bit more about the concurrency: I found one strange problem: When connection1 has opened reading (prepared statement that was not finalized) and after that connection2 does some writing, then connection1 has to close (finalize) reading in order to be able to write. Sounds a bit complicated, but the general lesson is simple: As long as reads and writes are done in separate connections, there are no concurrency problems.

Comment: We have WAL enabled and are seeing this exception.

Comment: Your sqlite3 might be compiled without `HAVE_USLEEP` which makes concurrent threads wait for seconds before retrying and causes timeouts. https://beets.io/blog/sqlite-nightmare.html

Comment: Thank you @JanSlodicka! I was getting "General error: 5 database is locked" repeatedly until I tried to switch storage from a mounted drive to /tmp (local), and the error went away immediately! Thank you! :-D